# Uploading multiple images with AJAX empty php response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I'm Trying to upload multiple images via post AJAX method, but if I upload more than 2 pictures, I get empty array response from PHP, but with 1 or 2, and sometimes 3 images, I get successful response! data is passed successfully to PHP all times, but response is like mystery !

my ajax

```
var id=data;
                         var file_data=$('#images').prop('files');        
                         var formData = new FormData();
                         for(var x in file_data){
                            formData.append("image["+x+"]", file_data[x]);
                         }
                         formData.append("id", id);
                         $.ajax({
                            url: "ajax/ajax_add_car.php?veids=2",
                            enctype: "multipart/form-data",
                            method: "POST",
                            data: formData,
                            cache:false,
                            processData: false,
                            contentType: false,
                            success: function(data){
                                console.log(data);
                            },

                         })
```

mine PHP response:

```
foreach($_FILES as $lolz){
print_r($lolz);
```

}
print_r($_POST);

Comment: What is your max_post_size in your php.ini? That is the most likely culprit - by default it is set to 8MB (and sometimes set lower in production).